# Как установить два пароля для su?

Tags: linux, debian, ldap, su

- Debian 9

Возможно ли установить два пароля для su? И если да, то я так понимаю, мне необходимо копать в сторону PAM? Подскажите, что для этого надо? Хотелось бы поэкспериментировать, виртуалки не имею, а запороть систему как-то не хочется.

> When you're prompted for a password, that's usually PAM's doing. By editing its config you can completely customize that (e.g., you could ask for two passwords, or none at all, or a one-time password, or...).

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166134/basic-explanation-on-nss-ldap-and-pam).

Comment: «виртуалки не имею» — заведите ;) А можно поинтересоваться, зачем два-то?

Comment: @andreymal, ну, для общего развития))

Comment: А почему не `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

Самый универсальный, простой и надёжный способ - сделать второго пользователя с uid=0, и уже ему дать другой пароль.
В BSD системах этот метод изначально был прописан как штатный (второй звался toor; у пользователя root был шелл csh, а у toor - sh).
Команду для вызова надо будет набирать не "su", а "su toor", с нужными опциями.

Comment: Спасибо! А не расскажете, пожалуйста, про самый неуниверсальный, сложный и опасный способ?